# High level advice for working with Graphics (A map with Icons, Pan & Zoom support)

Tags: java, android, graphics, maps, pan

I'm new to Android and Java. I want to be able to use an image as a background, let's pretend it's a map. Then I want to overlay icons (other graphics) on top of the map at specific coordinates and I want to know when the user clicks on these icons, so I can render text next to them. I also want pan & zoom support.

Is there a control that can handle all this automatically or do I need to be working with a canvas and implementing all this stuff msyelf.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how big your map is.  Assuming that your map is not too big you could just use a canvas.  All you would do just blit your map to the background, then draw your icons over it.  If your map is a bit larger, you may have to chop it up into chunks, then do some range searching to get only the chunks and icons which are visible.  If it is really big, then maybe you should look some of the standard map drawing APIs out there.

Comment: I see Google has a Map View API. I wonder if I can override their onDraw event and draw my own bitmap as the map rather than download their tiles.

Comment: Ah, I see.  I forgot to ask you how big it was and had just assumed that it was a smaller thing.  Google's map view API does look pretty good, but I've never used it myself.  I would say if you need something like that, why not give it a shot?  In all likelihood it sounds like exactly what you need from the description.

Comment: Yeah, I found it after I asked. The maps I would be using are small so I can load them all into memory. If I get this project I'll try using that API and overriding the onDraw event to see if it works.